# pgfplot stacked chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

just a few question about the chart showed in the picture below:

1. how can I place the legend of the  in a way that the top of the columns is shown?
2. how can I add the % symbol to the data?
3. how can I up the first two data just to avoid the intersection with the x-axis?

I post the picture of what I actually have and the code.

Thanks for your support!

[image]

```
 \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  title={Porcentaje anual sobre el total afiliados a la Seg. Social seg\'un    nacionalidad},
  ybar stacked, ymin=0, 
bar width=10mm,
symbolic x coords={2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007},
xtick=data,
yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={anchor=north},%Move values in bar
totals/.style={nodes near coords align={anchor=south}},
x tick label style={anchor=south,yshift=-0.5cm},
%every node near coord/.style={
  %},
  ]
 %Active
 \addplot [fill=blue!50] coordinates {
({2003},5.6)
({2004},6.3)
({2005},9.3)
({2006},9.7)
({2007},10.3)};
%Inactive
\addplot [fill=red!50, point meta=explicit] coordinates {
({2003},94.4) [94.4]
({2004},93.7) [93.7]
({2005},90.7) [90.7]
({2006},90.3) [90.3]
({2007},89.7) [89.7]};
\legend{Extranjeros afiliados a la S. Social s/total,Espa\~noles afiliados a la S. Social s/total}
 %Dummy stacked plot to produce totals
 \addplot[totals] coordinates {
 ({2003},0)
 ({2004},0)
 ({2005},0)
 ({2006},0)
 ({2007},0)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to have addressed all your points. Please see the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  title={Porcentaje anual sobre el total afiliados a la Seg. Social seg\'un    nacionalidad},
  ybar stacked, ymin=0, 
bar width=10mm,
symbolic x coords={2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007},
xtick=data,
yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={anchor=north},%Move values in bar
totals/.style={nodes near coords align={anchor=south}},
x tick label style={anchor=south,yshift=-0.5cm},
legend style={at={(1,1.2)}}, %<-place the legend outside of the plot 
title style={yshift=1cm}, %<-move the title up
ymin=-10,%<-move the axis up
yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\%}%<- add percent
%every node near coord/.style={
  %},
  ]
 %Active
 \addplot [fill=blue!50] coordinates {
({2003},5.6)
({2004},6.3)
({2005},9.3)
({2006},9.7)
({2007},10.3)};
%Inactive
\addplot [fill=red!50, point meta=explicit] coordinates {
({2003},94.4) [94.4]
({2004},93.7) [93.7]
({2005},90.7) [90.7]
({2006},90.3) [90.3]
({2007},89.7) [89.7]};
\legend{Extranjeros afiliados a la S. Social s/total,Espa\~noles afiliados a la S. Social s/total}
 %Dummy stacked plot to produce totals
 \addplot[totals] coordinates {
 ({2003},0)
 ({2004},0)
 ({2005},0)
 ({2006},0)
 ({2007},0)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]